# Rails is parsing a request as html even though it's json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create an api with Rails.  When I try to issue an ajax request with json in the browser like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://localhost:3000',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

The rails server is looking at it like html, as can be seen from the logs:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-08-12 13:52:00 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by LandingsController#index as HTML
```

It should say as JSON since the request is JSON.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think `dataType` only tells jQuery to parse the response as a JSON. It does not tell the server that you are requesting a JSON. Taken from the doc : *"The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."*

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on how your routing is set, not only what you pass in request. You should set default format in `routes.rb` like so:

```
root 'your_root_controller#index', format: 'json'
```

Should work in Rails 4 & 5.